# bootstrap simple Carousel compatibility with IE8 and 9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, carousel

I have a simple Bootstrap carousel slider but the sliding effect does not work in ie8 and ie9 , I am not an Expert coder, I have searched on internet but was unable to find a perfect answer, can anyone guide me how can I solve this issue of transitions in ie8 and ie9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it ... this works for me

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script src="js/ie-bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```